# Coldfusion Sendgrid API for call "re-subscribe" user email

Tags: coldfusion, sendgrid, cfml, cfc, lucee

- Application Server :  ColdFusion 11 & Lucee
- OS : Windows 2012

Trying to call sendgrid API for re-subscribe user, sendgrid giving most of the languages code examples on sendgrid website but there is not example available for coldfusion.
please find attached code and error screen shoot.

ERROR:
[image: Sendgrid API call]

Code:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.sendgrid.com/api/stats.getAdvanced.json" method="POST" result="returnStruct">
<cfhttpparam name="api_user" value="myAccountUserName" type="formfield">
<cfhttpparam name="api_key" value="mykeyExAmPlE" type="formfield">
```

Comment: See "filecontent" Bad username and password.

Comment: @RahulVyas but password is right in using same for login there account

Comment: Are you sending all this parameter  api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&start_date=2013-01-01&end_date=2013-01-02&data_type=global

see this link 
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/statistics_advanced.html

Some arguments are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<cfhttp url="https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/asm/suppressions/global/emailAddress@unsub.com" method="delete" result="returnStruct3">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" value="Basic #ToBase64('accountUserName:AccountPassword')#" type="header">
</cfhttp>`